# Issue installing solc npm

Tags: npm, solidity

When I try to install solc (**npm install solc** or **npm install -g solc**) I actually can install it BUT when looking for it (through the command **which solc**) nothing shows up.
Another strange thing: when looking for solcjs (through the command **which solc**) i get the correct path where it is indeed installed.

Things which I have already tried : uninstalling solc and solcjs and then re-installing them (which led to the same problem)

Other details : when I am in node.js and i try to do something like var solc = require('solc') no errors arise. Pretty strange one may think, well that's two of us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to share the knowledge my collegue has finally shared with me: for my issue the following commands solved the problem (I did not initially mentioned that i was working on a MacOs my bad).

Step 1: Uninstall all possible version of solc (npm uninstall solc)

Step 2: brew tap ethereum/ethereum

Step 3: brew install solidity

This led to the correct creation of the path where solc is installed

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the solc command line usage documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#usage-on-the-command-line) and [this question on the ethereum stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6346/solc-version-command-not-found), you're not *supposed* to.

But, if you insist on doing so, it's best if you add solc's installation directory to your `$PATH`.

Comment: Actually that's not possible sisnce then command "wchich solc" does not give me any installation path

Comment: Checking the solidity documentation [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html), you're not gonna get anything. The documentation *literally* says "The commandline executable is named solcjs". You could make an alias if you want though.